# How can I make div container with 3 images auto resizable?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve similar effect as is on this page: http://ketrawars.com

When you try to resize a browser window, all images resize along with it. I can get that working if my div contains one image to which I set width 100%. However, I have a problem when I need to put 3 images one next to another.

My code:

```
<div class="content">
    <img  src="images/main_01.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="content">
    <img src="images/main_02.png" alt="" />
    <img src="images/main_03.png" alt="" />
    <img src="images/main_04.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {

  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This is what it does:
[image]

And this is what is desired:
[image]

With the option to write text on the middle image (second one).

Comment: is there a reason not to place the images as background images in CSS? They can be scaled in CSS using `background-size`. This would make centering the images easier. Also, it will make it easier to place text over the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have three equally sized images, then set each of their widths to 32%:

```
.content img {
    width:32%;
}
```

`img` elements are displayed as `inline`, by default. **This means that the browser will add inline space between them, causing line breaks- you must subtract a percentage or two to compensate for this space.**

I recommend displaying the images as blocks and then floating them to remove the inline space.

```
.content img {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

**If your images aren't equally sized, simply set their percentages so that all of the elements' widths add to 100.**

Another good way to ensure that things will resize with the screen to use viewport units: `vw` and `vh`. They're defined as 1/100 the width and height of the viewport, respectively. Only Gecko based browsers will update them dynamically, however.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXyOdv)

Comment: Thank you, but these images are not having the same width :(. However I will try some experimentation in that area. Thank you.

Comment: @OndrejTokar sorry, I forgot to imply: as long as the width percentages for all three elements adds to 100, they can be different widths. This goes for any `n` elements in a container.